# How to deal with the need to raise WPF Validation.ErrorEvent in code behind

Tags: .net, wpf, validation

There is this user control. It contains validation logic. The user control contains several input controls. These input controls are not invalid or valid on their own, but the combination of these values in the input controls is either valid or not. This means that a validation error never arises. Because no binding will ever cause a validation error. The ViewModel (re)validates itself when it notices any of the values in the input controls have changed and sets its IsValid property.

Now in a parent view this control is implemented, among other input controls, and the parent catches validation errors using the following event.

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(ParentView), Validation.ErrorEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ValidationError));
```

The issue is that the user control is not raising this event, because there is not control with a binding that is invalid. (Due to the validity depends on the combination of values, not a single control).

Currently I am looking at raising this `Validation.ErrorEvent` in code behind, but I doubt that is the way to go, if it would work at all.

How would I go about this?

Comment: tried NotifyOnValidationError="True" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216321/wpf-validation-error-event-doesnt-fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I go about this?

Maybe this is not what you want to hear but the way to go about this is to use a view model class that implements the IDataErrorInfo or INotifyDataErrorInfo and then bind the view elements to source properties of this one. Please refer to the following blog post for more about this and data validation in WPF in general: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/.

You then effectively move your validation logic to the view model and can test it separately without any views. If you have several views that are dependant on each other you could implement a view model class per view and then have a "parent" view model class where the final validation is performed. Trying to pass routed events between different views seems like a quite bad idea in my opinion. MVVM is *the* recommended design pattern for XAML based applications for a reason. You should really look into it if haven't already: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx

Comment: I used `INotifyDataErrorInfo` in every parent -> child relation, cascading the event to the top most parent. Which finally triggers this `Validation.ErrorEvent`. Thanks for the help.